# How to have multiple domains on 1 digital ocean droplet sharing self cert ssl cert

Tags: nginx, ssl-certificate, digital-ocean

I have created a cert like this:
Following steps from:

- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate-for-nginx-in-ubuntu-16-04

```
sudo openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout /etc/ssl/private/nginx-selfsigned.key -out /etc/ssl/certs/ nginx-selfsigned.crt
```

Using my domain example:

- **Common Name (e.g. server FQDN or YOUR name):** [www.examplesite1.com](http://www.examplesite1.com)

Within the article it says I can have only 1 default server, which I assume the self cert will work on.

Lets say I have 2 websites on my nginx like this:

1. **/etc/nginx/sites-available/examplesite1.com**
2. **/etc/nginx/sites-available/examplesite2.com**

Both with config that looks like this: (with examplesite2.com for 2nd example.)

Notice, I am forwarding to a proxy server - node.js in my case.

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name examplesite1.com www.examplesite1.com;
  return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
  client_max_body_size 10G;
  location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    proxy_redirect off;
  }
}
server {
    # SSL configuration
    server_name www.examplesite1.com www.www.examplesite1.com;
    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
    include snippets/self-signed.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;
}
```

Symlinks appropriately set:

```
ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/examplesite1.com /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/examplesite1.com
ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/examplesite2.com /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/examplesite2.com
```

If I change 'default_server' to my url, it breaks the nginx config

```
  listen 443 ssl http2 www.examplesite1.com;
```

> Error
> nginx: [emerg] invalid parameter "www.examplesite1.com" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/examplesite1.com:18
> nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed

The problem is if I keep default_server like this it then does not forward proxy to my nginx server and goes to my default server, which is my nginx index.html landing page which is not desired.

Answer (score 0):

I realised my mistake
This code was never reached in the first server block so needed to go into the listen:443 server block:

```
  location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    proxy_redirect off;
  }
```

The reference to default_server did not break it but I have removed it anyway.

Updated now:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name examplesite1.com www.examplesite1.com;
  # redirect to https
  return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
server {
    # SSL configuration
    server_name examplesite1.com www.examplesite1.com;

    # remove redirect and replae with proxy stuff here...
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    include snippets/self-signed.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;
    location / {
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
      proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
      proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```